# Creating Cordova plugin with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm creating Cordova plugin for Ionic 2. I receive datas from Android, and show it in console or Alert, but I'm not able to show it on html view.

```
device: any[] = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            private appService: AppService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    devices_activity.devicesActivity(this.success, this.failure);
}

success(aL) {

    for (var i = aL.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        aL[i];
        console.log('name: ' + aL[i]);
    }
}

failure() {
    alert("Error calling Devices Stone SDK Plugin");
}
```

I tried to put `aL` in `device` array, but I got an error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'device' of null`

How can I show the items received from Android in html View?

Comment: Where's your HTML?  This doesn't seem like an Ionic/Cordova question but an Angular 2 question.  If those variables are coming through in your console log, you're probably just not binding to variables properly between your angular component and template.  Maybe if the success function did something like aL = device I'd see where you're exposing it for two way binding in the template, but it looks like your code doesn't handle that from what I can see, which I'd guess is your problem, if that makes sense

Comment: I tried to do aL = device, but I got an error. it say `device is null`

Comment: sorry, my bad, I flipped that assignment statement.  Should be device = aL

Comment: I would like to put `aL` in `device`, and after this use the two way binding

Comment: I tried too `this.device = aL`

Comment: I can't help you too much with this unless I see the template and how you want your data to display.  If you're getting the data in that code and it's not rendering on your HTML then we need to bridge that divide.  From your code it looks like you're working with a list, but I'm not sure that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you getting this `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'device' of null` for `this.device = aL` also?

Comment: Yes, I had this error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you `device` variable is out of scope inside `success` function. Try to use this. I think this should resolve your issue.

```
device: any[] = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            private appService: AppService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  var scope = this;
  devices_activity.devicesActivity((aL: any) => {
    scope.device = aL;
  }, () => {
    alert("Error calling Devices Stone SDK Plugin");
  });
}
```

Comment: @VictorMendes Glad to help :).